# Linking table in same SQL Server database to find or match data easier

Tags: sql-server, database

I will be having multiple tables depends on how many type of data I will be receive after reading a file.

So far I have done creating and insert all the data accordingly into multiple tables where they should belong to.

How to link those table together in a same database so that I can find the repeated data in different tables.

I need to match all the multiple tables together so that I can find or match all the data together to see how many times they have appear in different tables and allocate where are them. Is there anyway to do so? My previews coding is done in Python Pyodbc module, about this linking table, it can be done in a SQL Server query right?

When I want to know how many times the 4 has appear in the column No_Person_in_the_room in both tables or more tables, it will shows the number of 4 has appear how many times in all the tables

[image]

And also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Honestly there should be just one table (PersonRoleRelationship) which will hold all relationships between different Person roles (because same person can have different roles in different relationships). This structure would make it very simple to query the Parent - Child relationship to query. A sample database structure will look like this:

[image]

2) If the database redesign is not possible, then you can add a new column having calculated hash values for the columns you need which can then be used to compare among different tables.

Comment: What if there is thousand of these tables? I want to link them all in a same database, and find out how many of A has appear in there, or how many of B appears in Column C

Comment: When you say 'thousand of these tables', what exactly do you mean? Is it thousands of different relationships (which will be handled easily by the PersonRelationship table)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: it is not relationship as in father, family or teacher. It is collecting data, For Example: there is column( Building Name, Building Floor,Room Number, Number of Person stay in the Room) then there will be thousand of different table of data set but the column remain the same, just the row is different due to the input data. Then when I want to know how many times the 4 person stay in a room has appear in all the tables or how many times the Building Floor has repeated for different Building Name with 3 persons stay in a room. Hope u get what i mean. Tq

Comment: Unfortunately not - I am struggling to understand. Can you post some sample data and your expected results?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question v photo, pls take a look, I would Expected when I search: **No_Person_in_the_room** with **4** , it will shows how many times that the **4** has appears in both tables or more tables.